# copying files from one computer to another - whole disks

Tags: windows, internet, data-transfer

What's the best solution to copy files from one computer to another via internet. Computers are using windows. Do you think that ftp is good idea?

--Edit--

It should be easy to make for normal user and fast so it can copy whole 160 GB disk in reasonable time. Once only by house (?W)lan or USB cable.

Comment: 'Best' is vague. Simplest? Easy for one time? Easy for continuous copies? Easy to automate?

Comment: Reasonable time? For 160GB...it can take a long time depending on your Internet connection speed. That has nothing to do with how you do it though.

Comment: I have a feeling that you have two machines on home lan and you are looking for the fastest way to transfer data b/w them. correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

ftp in general will be a bad idea. It's hard to set up, hard to firewall, and username/passwords are sent in the clear with no encryption.

If it's one time, and not anything very private, you could look at megaupload.com or rapidshare.com

If you have a dropbox account, that's a possibility.

If it's small enough, you can email to yourself or add to google docs, or MS Live SkyDrive or whatever they're calling it.

If you need to do it often, my personal toolkit would be [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) where I could install a webserver or an SSH server. This may be too much work for a typical person though.

Answer (score 0):

FTP would require quite a bit from you to make it work...Make one an FTP server, open firewall ports, etc.

Just used TeamViewer, and use the File Transfer Option.

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx